# remove seasonality in future contracts

Tags: time-series, futures, derivatives, commodities

very new to commodities.

I have raw agriculture future data, and I need to remove the seasonality (de-seasonalize) from the data, what is the general approach ? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you may have different seasonalities in the data as per each agricultural commodity characteristics. My guess is that there may be seasonality within the year as per the specific commodity depending if one or more harvestings occur a year. Also due to the specific unceirtanty due to planting, growth season and harvesting times. In addition also longer than a year seasonalities may occur due to long term atmosferic cycles (el niño for example) which may cause spread of plagues, watter shortages or abundances.

I would take a look into http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deseasonalize/deseasonalize.pdf for R.

Answer (score 0):

Answered this in respect of power and gas, please have a look at [How to de-seasonalize natural gas term structure data?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/14225/how-to-de-seasonalize-natural-gas-term-structure-data)